# Does "Show by insertion" make sense mathematically?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrases, mathematics

In math classes you might be given an equation like

> 2+x=5

and a valute like x=3. In my native Danish tongue I could now say one of the following:

> Vis ved indsættelse, at x=3 er en løsning.

> Vis ved at gøre prøve, at x=3 er en løsning.

These directly translate to:

> Show by insertion that x=3 is a solution.

> Show by testing that x=3 is a solution.

Are this direct/literal translations correct? Is "show by insertion" meaningful for this purpose? Obviously the point is that the given value should be input in place of the x in the equation, but is this phrase how an English speaker would refer to such an action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the verb **substitute**.

An example is on this basic math page [math is fun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/substitution.html):

> **Substitution**
> In Algebra "Substitution" means putting numbers where the letters are:
> When we have: *x − 2*
> And we know that *x* = 6 ...
> then we can "substitute" 6 for *x*:
> 6 − 2 = 4

So the translation is (in your example)

> Show by **substitution** that x=3 is a solution.